# Perl read and print Line by line

Tags: perl

I am trying to get a line by line print out for the following:

```
My info


info | info | info |
-------------------------
1    |  1   | 
2
3
.
.
.
```

I am using this to code but it is unable to print out as what I expect.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'myfile.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   

    if ($line =~ /info | info | info | /) {
        print $line;    
        last if $. == 10;
    }
}
close $info;
```

Is there something missing or going wrong in the code?

The expected result should print out on CMD

```
info | info | info |
-------------------------
1    |  1   | 
2
3
.
.
.
```

Comment: The pipe (|) is a special character in regular expressions

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: @harmic I am expecting it to print out the portion from "My info to ." its a text file

Comment: `if ($line =~ /\Qinfo | info | info |/ .. 10)` => http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: @M42 I have modified the questions and added in the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'myfile.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $print = 0;
while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    $print = 1 if $line =~ /^info/;
    print $line if $print;
    last if $. == 10;
}
close $info;
```

*Update according to comment:*

If you want to match `info: ** info`, you have to escape metacharacters (here the `*` character):

```
$print = 1 if $line =~ /^info: \*\* info/;
```

and, if have optional spaces:

```
$print = 1 if $line =~ /^\s*info:\s*\*\*\s*info/;
```

Comment: @user1204868:May be you have some space characters before the word `info`? Change the regex to: `/^\s*info/`.

Comment: can I check with u, what if there is a * and : in the line that I need to look at for info. For example, I am trying to do this /^info: ** info/, is there a way to include the * and : ?

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to do this in Perl would be to use [the range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), commonly known as a flip-flop:

```
perl -ne'print if /^info/ .. eof' yourfile.txt
```

In a program file it would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print if /^info/ .. eof;
}
```

Comment: A benefit with `eof` is that it makes it possible to use multiple files.

Comment: `$.` should never be `0`, although `eof` makes more clear intention.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
while(<DATA>) { print $_, unless($_!~m/^$/ && $_!~m/My info/i && $. >= '10'); }

__DATA__
My info
info | info | info |
-------------------------
1    |  1   | 
2
3
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks! But the information in my text file is not a fixed text. Row "1" can become 4 | 2 | and so on

Comment: shall I know how do you want to print the text line by line or pattern matching? Since I said to the code to print every line (Contains value) should be print as output. Thanks.

Comment: further understanding you will print the output corresponding to your input

Comment: pattern matching. As the rows after ---- will not be fixed.